# How to position a rectangle from canvas in the top of the window in Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

Can someone help me in **Kivy**?

How can i position a Rectangle from **canvas** in the **top of the window of any resolution**?

I have tried different ways but didn't find the solution, i really appreciate it if someone could help me!

See image below, you will understand what i mean. I want to move that Shape into the top of the window, actually not with "pos", i want to move it with a way to make it possible to change it's size in any resolution.

Thanks.

[image: Kivy using canvas]

**EDIT :**

```
<Test>:
BoxLayout:
    size: root.width, root.height
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 1,1,1,1
        RoundedRectangle:
            id: toprect
            size: self.width,root.height/5
            radius: [(0, 0), (0, 0), (40, 40), (40, 40)]
```

Comment: Use `from kivy.core.window import Window`, then access `Window.size` to get the size of the window in pixels. Using that information you can draw your rectangle at whatever pos and size suits you.

Comment: @inclement i found something, but for example if the height is 800 and i use it for positioning my rectangle, it will disappear. because the positioning start from the left-bottom, what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

**If you have a .kv file:**

Add this to your .kv file:

<Your Class Name>:
    FloatLayout:
        your image displays here
            **pos_hint: {"x": 0.3, "y": 0.5}**
            size_hint: 0.6, 0.6

The pos_hint (Hinting the position) and the FloatLayout gives the screen a dynamic layout. If you were to resize the screen on any side of the window, all the elements  on the screen that are inside the FloatLayout will expand in proportion. Change the y value to any number, and the following image will change accordingly (Note that in the pos_hint tag, you can use any of the following: x, y, top, bottom, left, right). If the following code doesn't work, go to your python file and type this on the top:

```
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
```

Then at the screen where it displays the image, make that class inherit from the FloatLayout class.

**If you don't have a .kv file:**

Go to your python file and look for the class that has the build method. Copy the class name and create a new file called yourClassNameHere.kv. If your class name has an 'app' in it, name your .kv file the same but take out the 'app' (Note: Your .kv filename has to be in all lowercase).

For example:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget


class MyWindow(Widget):
    pass

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWindow()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Then my .kv file would be named **my.kv** in my working directory. After your created your kv file, follow the steps for if you have a kv file.

Comment: Thanks but i am using canvas! these property that you mentioned not working on my codes (i mean not work on canvas). actually i have to use canvas to create shapes (create GUI), if i use images they will change in any size and become weird. please check again my post i have added my code.